# Mezuza on an elevator?

Tags: halacha, mezuzah, architecture-design

Today I walked into a building and discovered that someone had taped a mezuza onto the "doorpost" of the elevator.  The elevator is about 1m x 1m square - way too small for a room to justify having a mezuza - and besides which, even if the elevator were 4x4 amos (minimum measure for a "room"), would the elevator require a mezuza, bearing in mind that the "room" keeps moving, and most of the time the mezuza is simply "guarding" an open shaft?

Is there even a documented chumra of putting a mezuza in such a position?  Or this just a *bizayon* (disgrace) of the mitzva, and should I protest about it?

[image]

Comment: What kind of building was it? Who owns it?

Comment: @Slaks - residential building.  Don't understand your 2nd question... who said anything about a closet?

Comment: Including in your question a source for the assertion that four by four _amos_ is the minimum size for a room that gets a _m'zuza_ would be nice.

Comment: Was it on the right (implying the elevator is a subordinate storage room) or the left (implying a corridor to the next room)?

Comment: Maybe a shaar to enter the house

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is discussed by R' Yitzchak Weiss [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1598&st=&pgnum=495), and see a brief summary in English [here](http://www.vbm-torah.org/archive/salt-devarim/46-3ekev.htm).

R' Weiss identifies one Acharon that would logically require a mezuza on an elevator door (the inner door to the elevator itself) even if the elevator is less that 4x4 amos. He rules, therefore, that one should affix a mezuza to an elevator without a b'racha. He acknowledges, though, that those that do not wish to have a mezuza on their elevator door have whom to rely on halachically. The "outer" door to the elevator shaft, however, would definitely not require a mezuza.

Answer (score 2):

The owner is probably not aware of the halachos, but how about this for limud z'chus:

We are machmir to put mezuzos even on a bais shaar- meaning any corridor which will eventually, even if not immediately, lead to a 4x4 utilized room ([Shulchan Aruch YD 286:7](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9147&st=&pgnum=224) like the yesh omrim).  This elevator corridor does that, it's just a little mobile.  Then you would need another one on the right as you exit the elevator on the 2nd floor.

I don't know if the above idea has any validity, just an idea.

Answer (score 1):

See the article ["Does an Elevator Require a Mezuzah?"](http://e.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/shiur.asp?id=14271) by R' Yirmiyohu Kaganoff.

Comment: The answer would be better had you summarized the article and the rabbi's conclusions.